# VScode refresh workspace

Tags: java, visual-studio-code

VScode does a fair bit of magic when a new project is opened, it seems. One thing that it does is detects my java project (built with gradle) in my multi-root configuration, which is essential for development.

I have 3 root directories, say, `workspace/my-repo/{python-app, java-app, node-app}` and I have a workspace `simple.code-workspace` file with the following `folders` specified:

```
  "folders": [
    {
      "path": "../python-app"
    },
    {
      "path": "../java-app"
    },
    {
      "path": "../node-app"
    }
  ],
```

And a trillion other settings which I hope are not relevant. It just so happens that I recently added the `java-app` folder. Now, when I load this workspace it does not detect my `Java Project` properly for `java-app`. However, if I make **an exact copy** of the workspace file, `simple-2.code-workspace` and open this workspace, everything works swimmingly.

I assume that `simple` workspace has some sort of cache and therefore the magic vscode does the first time a workspace is loaded is not being executed?

Comment: VS Code takes the open folder as the workspace, so you should open the Java project's folder correctly.